# Here is my table giving me error: Undefine control sequence error

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Possible Cases }
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.5cm} p{2.5cm} p{1.5cm} p{7cm} p{2.5cm}}
\toprule
 \head {Cases} & \head {Power consumption}  & \head {RTEP} & \head {Cost}\\
\midrule
 \rmfamily Min$\varphi(t)$,Min $\varepsilon(t)$& \rmfamily 1.5 & \rmfamily 8.11 & \rmfamily 12.16\\
  \rmfamily Max$\varphi(t)$,Min$\varepsilon(t)$ & \rmfamily 13.84 & \rmfamily 8.11&\rmfamily 112.24\\
  \rmfamily Min$\varphi(t)$,Max$\varepsilon(t)$&\rmfamily 1.5 &\rmfamily 13.84& \rmfamily 112.24\\
  \rmfamily Max$\varphi(t)$,Max$\varepsilon(t)$ &\rmfamily 13.84 & \rmfamily27.35& \rmfamily378.5\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\label{table:trade} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please don't post such fragments only. Which error is reported? Which control sequence? (I also removed the unrelated tags [tag:tableofcontents] and [tag:biblatex])

Comment: I do not know the `\head` macro, but it is generally no good idea to put a space between the macro and its arguments as in `\head {Cases}`. [I believe that this is a macro with its argument ...]

Comment: @Jürgen: Checked it -- I confused `\head` with `\thead` from `makecell` package

Comment: Can any one draw this table for me for double column PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Min}{Min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{Max}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
  \centering
  \caption{Possible Cases }
  \begin{tabular}{lSSS[table-format=3.2]}
    \toprule
    \thead {Cases} & {\thead {Power & & \\ consumption}} & {\thead {RTEP}} & {\thead {Cost}}\\
    \midrule
    $ \Min\varphi (t), \Min\varepsilon (t) $ & 1.5 & 8.11 & 12.16 \\
    $ \Max\varphi (t), \Min\varepsilon (t) $ & 13.84 & 8.11 & 112.24 \\
    $ \Min\varphi (t), \Max\varepsilon (t) $ & 1.5 & 13.84 & 112.24 \\
    $ \Max\varphi (t), \Max\varepsilon (t) $ & 13.84 & 27.35 & 378.5 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:trade} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: of topics: what means `Max ...` and `Min`? i know for `max` and `min` ... is this some new math or just OP innovation?  :(

Comment: I suppose it's the O.P.'s version for ` min` and `max`$. Maybe he/she has good reasons to denote them so.

Comment: Dear Bernard! 
Thank you. you're just amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use \hline in plac3e of bottom rule and mid rule. It should work well.

Comment: How you know, that use of the `\hline` will solve OP's problem? (S)he didn't provide any relevant information about error nor document, so it is hard to help him (her).

Answer (score 0):

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% \toprule, \bottomrule, \midrule belong to package. I have removed %them. Just use \hrule as shown here.

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h]
\caption{Possible Cases }
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{ p{4 cm} p{3 cm} p{3 cm} p{3cm}}\hline
  \bf {Cases} & \bf {Power}  & \bf {RTEP} & \bf {Cost}\
& \bf{consumption} & \
  \hline
%\head is not defined.
&&& \
  Min$\varphi(t)$,Min $\varepsilon(t)$&  1.5 & 8.11 &  12.16\
  &&&\
   Max$\varphi(t)$,Min$\varepsilon(t)$ & 13.84 &  8.11& 112.24\
   &&&\
  Min$\varphi(t)$,Max$\varepsilon(t)$& 1.5 &  13.84& 112.24\
  &&& \
   Max$\varphi(t)$,Max$\varepsilon(t)$ & 13.84 & 27.35& 378.5\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
\label{table:trade} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table*}
\end{document}
% Since no packages are added here, I have to remove them I have tested it. If you need a gap between line just add &&&\. Sorry I forgot to see gmail. I use vaman_kulkarni2005@yahoo.com regulalry.

Comment: Since you already added an answer to this question earlier, please consider editing this [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/538839/134144) using the `edit` button in the bottom left of your answer. Your code will be better readable if  you indent the corresponding lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please also keep in mind that your table exceeds the current textwidth by almost 60 pt. Is there a reason why you chose `p` type columns instead of instead of `l`, `c`, or `r` here?